# What are the limits of "user-initiated" play events on html5 mobile video player

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, video

It seems to be a common complaint that mobile devices won't autoplay video or audio. According to the Apple Developer Library it is disabled on purpose:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

What is allowed is for a direct user action to trigger the play event. My problem is that I have thumbnails of videos which when clicked load a video element in their place and need to play once they are loaded. On mobile the user has to click twice to make the video play which is not good. I am frustrated because my user actually *is* triggering a play action but there are a few other events which take place in between. I started testing a different user-triggered-event to see what the scope or limitations of what apple calls a "direct user action" are.

I found that this code triggered the play event:

```
$(".clickElement").click(function(){
    $("video").get(0).play();
});
```

while this did not:

```
$(".clickElement").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("video").get(0).play();
    },0);
});
```

the same went for different timeout durations and when setInterval was used instead.

My question is what / how does apple define a direct user action? Obviously timeouts and intervals aren't direct enough. Is there a way for me to trigger the play event "directly" from the user and allow enough time for my video element to enter the page?

Comment: What happens when you do this? $(".clickElement").click(function(e){
    setTimeout(function(_e){
        $("video").get(0).play();
    }.call(this, e),0);
});

Comment: very interesting! ok so what happens is when used after the video element has already loaded this trigger works. however when i put it into practice, using it after the video element has loaded, it fails. it appears that attaching the original click event to the setTimeout makes it trigger at the same time the original click event occurs, making setTimeout disregard it's ability to timeout at all. However this shows that it is not about being nested inside of other functions which prevent the action from being "user initiated" rather it seems that it must happen synchronously.

Comment: @billybardley not surprising you have to do it synchronously

Comment: for the record i also tried putting the play trigger inside of a while loop that checked whether the video element existed before exiting. even when the while loop was declared after the ajax call that generates the video element there occurred an infinite loop and prevented anything else from proceeding. i think i'm out of luck on this one : \